# Why control doesn't pick up the generic style defined for the controls of it's type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, wpf-style

I am trying to apply the following style for all the **border**s in my form:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5076A7" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
    </Style>

    <Style ... />

  <UserControl.Resources>
```

However my **border** inside my **ListView** and also non of the other borders pick up this style unless I use the `x:Key FooSyle` value and refer to the key in my `<Boder Style={StaticResource FooStyle}>` which if for sure not what I want to do.

The border is mentioned below:

```
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
              <Border>
                <Grid Margin="2">
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         ...
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: It's embedded in a ControlTemplate, that's why. You can either declare it explicitly like you were saying with Style= or you could throw it in the control template or a BasedOn declaration pointing to the template.

Comment: @ChrisW. for the second suggestion, wouldn't `BasedOn` need to target the same type? and also Is being embedded in general an issue or only `ControlTemplate` has this nature? Just want to understand it a little bit more.

Comment: Think of a ControlTemplate as its own beast, oblivious to anything else in the current DOM that it would/could inherit its styles from. You could though still specify that style somewhere in your view, or a resource dictionary or something and do like <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TheStyleName}"/> in the .Resources within that ControlTemplate instead of reiterating the whole template over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by allocating the Border Style to that Style's `<Style.Resources>` with is described as a **Nested Styles** concept such as below:

```
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
              <Border>
                <Grid Margin="2">
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                ...
                </Grid>
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style.Setters>
      <!--Nested Style-->
      <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
              <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </Style>
      </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written two style code for your problem.You can use Style.Resources or ControlTemplate.Resources.Also,you have found the right solution

Here is code:
(using DynamicResource)

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5076A7" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

 <ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Border Height="100" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewItemBorderStyle}">
                                <!--....-->
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Another one code( using StaticResource).It's embedded in a ControlTemplate

```
 <ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="ListViewItemBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5076A7" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                                </Style>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Border Height="100" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewItemBorderStyle}">
                                <!--....-->
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add BorderStyle in to ControlTemplate.Resources

Here is code:

```
  <ListView>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="asdasd"/>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Style x:Key="ListViewItemBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5076A7" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                                </Style>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Border Height="100" Style="{StaticResource ListViewItemBorderStyle}">
                             <!--....-->
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but why not rather in the `<Style.Resource>`?